# method for fastest allocation and free of dynamic sized array object as local variable

Tags: c++, memory-management

What is the method for fastest allocation and free of dynamic sized array object as local variable?

This is the standard but slowest way:

```
void func1(int n)
{
    int* array = new int[n];
    func2(array);
    delete array;
}
```

This is a better way, but it works ill in some compiler and OS, and sometimes fragile for code maintaining.

```
void func1(int n)
{
    int* array = _alloca(sizeof(int)*n);
    func2(array);
    _freea(array);
}
```

This is generic and fast (what I do for now), but this is cumbersome and sometimes comes across singleton destruction order issues.

```
void func1(int n)
{
    int* array = pool_alloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    func2(array);
    pool_free(array);
}
```

Is there any better way of taking both performance and conveniency?

Answer (score 3):

Create a helper class called `Buffer`.

```
struct Buffer
{
   Buffer(size_t s = 100) : size_(s), data_(new char[s]) {}
   ~Buffer() { delete [] data_; }

   void assureMinSize(size_t s)
   {
       if ( s > size_ )
       {
          delete [] data_;
          size_ = s;
          data_ = new char[s];
       }
   } 

   size_t size_;
   char* data_;
};
```

and use it as:

```
void func1(int n)
{
    static Buffer buffer;
    buffer.assureMinSize(n);
    func2(buffer.data_);
}
```

Comment: Why not `std::vector`?

Comment: Nice way. But it does not care >100 length. Workaround is add a condition routine for >100 length, but in that case, its speed goes down as normal heap access.

Comment: @SlavaZhuyko That is same to _the standard but slowest way_.

Comment: @HyunjikBae, if `n > 100`, the size of the buffer is reset to `n`. Next time you call the function with the same value of `n`, the buffer is ready to be used.

Comment: @RSahu Given that `buffer` is static, it is problematic because `func1` becomes non-reentrant. I removed `static`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no method of taking both performance and conveniency. You should use *new* in almost all cases. If you need performance in a limited environment, you should use *placement new*. If you sacrifice portability, you can use API call like HeapAlloc. But it is not necessarily faster.